# XAMPP for Mac cannot see PHP files

Tags: php, macos, xampp

I am unable to see php files after I downloaded XAMPP.  I am trying to write a php file, so I download and started XAMPP, but I cannot see PHP files show up.  When I open anything as simple as:

```
<?php
echo "Hello World";
?>
```

Just a blank Firefox window shows up. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Doesn't belong on this site. Would have been a question for superuser/serverfault or apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

What directory are you using for your PHP files? This needs to be in the htdocs directory in the xampp directory. Check to see if xampp is running by typing http://localhost in your browser URL. If you see the xampp page come up then it's working fine and you need to check if your PHP files are in the correct location. If nothing shows up then it's xampp that's not working.

I just checked for the document root directory on the xampp website. It's /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/ if you installed the xampp application in the applications directory.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I thought it could be boring to create lots of files in the "Applications" directory since it requires the super user right. How can enforce XAMPP to parse php files, residing in the directory created by ourselves, for instance "~/Sites/dir"?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess without an error message. Try this: edit your php.ini (I don't know where this would be in XAMPP, but you should be able to find it) and look for this variable setting:

```
display_errors
```

if it is set to Off, turn it to On, **then restart XAMPP**. When you load the page, you should see some meaningful error message on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

put the folder or files in the (lowercase) xampp folder.
Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/xampp
then try the url: localhost/xampp/folder/file.php
That should work.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the below is included in your httpd.conf

## Let Apache run phtml files

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .php5 .php4 .php3 .html .htm .phtml
```

Answer (score -2):

Apache will need a bit of configuration in the httpd.conf file before it treats PHP files with the respect they deserve.

(Only joking about the respect)

I'm using XAMPP for Windows, and I needed to add the following to the httpd.conf file:

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:/Program Files/xampp/apache/bin/php5apache2.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php5 .php4 .php3 .phtml
```

There may be some more details I've forgotten. It was a long time ago.

Comment: xampp should run out of the box for PHP with no configuration needed, also the question is for installation on a MAC so you LoadModule with a C:/ file base would not work since MAC OSX is based on UNIX

Comment: But that's why I said "I'm using XAMPP for Windows, and I needed to add the following". I assumed someone reading it would recognise it as a Windows example, and extrapolate.